# why the rvalue is deduced to be lvalue?

Tags: c++, rvalue

The code is attach as follow. i tried to implement a method to check the expression or varible's value type. but it seems failed to check rvalue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
void checkLValueRValue(T&& value) {
    using Type = decltype(std::forward<T>(value));
    if (std::is_lvalue_reference<Type>::value) {
        std::cout << "It's an lvalue reference." << std::endl;
    } else if (std::is_rvalue_reference<Type>::value) {
        std::cout << "It's an rvalue reference." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "It's not an lvalue or rvalue reference." << std::endl;
    }
}

class A {

};


int main() {
    int x = 42;
    int y = 43;
    int& lvalue_ref = x;
    int&& rvalue_ref = std::move(x);
    std::cout << std::is_rvalue_reference_v<A&&> << std::endl;

    checkLValueRValue(x);          // lvalue reference
    checkLValueRValue(lvalue_ref); // lvalue reference
    checkLValueRValue(std::move(x));// rvalue reference
    *checkLValueRValue(rvalue_ref); // it should be rvalue reference but not!*

    return 0;
}
```

the last checkLValueRvalue outputs It's an lvalue reference ? what happened ?

i am new to cpp, so i don't get it.

Comment: `rvalue_ref` is a lvalue expression, not a rvalue expression. All id-expressions naming variables are lvalue expressions, regardless of the variable's type. Should be explained in any introduction of rvalues references.

Comment: You're confusing rvalues/lvalues and rvalue/lvalue references. The former is a property of expressions, while the latter is a property of variables. The latter doesn't affect anything (except for `decltype` directly on a variable name, which you don't do), and the former affects overloading. Any variable name is an lvalue expression, even if the variable is an rvalue reference.

Comment: "_varible's value type_" makes no sense btw. There is the type of the variable and there is the _value category_ of an expression. There is no "_value type_".  And variables/objects don't have a value category, only a type.

Comment: Also remember that the difference of `lvalue reference` vs `rvalue reference` only matters at the time of reference binding and just restrict what they are allowed to bind to. After the binding is done, there is essentially no difference. That is to say, after `int i=5; int& ri=i; int&& rri = std::move(i);`, the expressions `i`, `ri` and `rri` are the same in all aspects: They are of type int and value category is lvalue, and they refer to the same object.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Mhm, except `decltype` can tell the difference between different kinds of references.

Comment: Of course, but I thought your comment already addressed that so I don't need to repeat. My apologies. Corrected message to OP: `decltype` is literally the only way you can observe any difference between  `i`, `ri`, and `rri`.